# I have text on a banner on my wordpress site and I am unable to get rid of it? Would appreciate any help or advice :-)

Tags: css

I hope you are all well.

I have text on a banner on my wordpress site and I am unable to get rid of it. The site was developed for me by a developer who I am no longer in contact with and I am trying to delete the text but to no avail. I've tried to look into lots of options such as settings etc however still I'm unable to remove it. I think in all things in life, it is probably a quick fix however if you don'[image]t know how, its very difficult.

Look forward to hearing your valuable thoughts.

Thanks,

David

Comment: This isn't answerable without seeing the code that implements it, I'd suggest hiring another developer

Comment: If it's not in options anywhere, it may be hard-coded, meaning you would need to search through the PHP theme files. If you're not comfortable doing so you'll likely need to hire someone.

Answer (score 0):

It can only be in the files or the database.

To Search the files:
Try searching in the file content for that text and delete it. If there are any quote marks around it, leave them in.

1. Download the website files
2. https://www.google.com/search?q=seach+file+content&oq=seach+file+content&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.2120j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

If it is not there try the Database:
1st - Make a backup copy of the database

1. download/Export the database
2. Search that database for that text
3. When you find which table it is in, navigate to that table and edit the column and remove the text. (Again be care of any content around it like quotes or square brackets.